# How to get Absolute Path from Complete path

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

Hi all `<var name="x" value="${toString:first}" />
<echo>${x}</echo>` this statements gives me the complete path of a file as `c:\prog\source....` i want to store from source only can anyone help me please

Comment: var is part of the ant-contrib extension. Not standard ANT. Read the doco. The use of "var" is discouraged: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html

Answer (score 0):

define a variable with the value c:/prog
and then you can always refer like ${k}/src where k is already defined as c:/prog , let me know if this helps

Comment: but why do i need ${k} i have a complete path i want to strip of the ${k} out of it i don't want to embed that with it

Comment: that is what I am trying to say , split your path in 2 variables , and at the time  of outputting the complete path, combine both of them , that way you will have option of changing one variable's value and keeping the other independent

Comment: it is giving the problem e.g. if i am setting [k=c:/prog] and my [src=c:/prog/abc/def..]and while echo [${k}/src=====> c:/prog/src] so it is not working i think you are confusing it as if my [src="abc/def"] and i want to add ["c:/prog"],no i already have [src=c:/prog/abc/def] but i want only [/abc/def].

Answer (score 0):

Use the relative attribute of the [property](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) task:

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

    <property name="x" location="source" relative="true"/>

    <target name="run">
        <echo message="x=${x}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```